# Method of Moments for Mixture distribution

Tags: moments, mixture-distribution, method-of-moments

> The restaurant owner also wants to reconfigure her seating layout, and has asked you for help in modeling her clients.
> She gives you a dataset of past reservations, and tells you that she gets a mix of single clients who come to sit at the bar, and people who come (alone or in groups) for dinner.
> You decide to model her clients using a mixture distribution, with fraction $\alpha$ of single bar patrons, and the remaining $(1-\alpha)$ fraction of diners; for the latter, you want to model the size of each group as $1+N_p$, where $N_p$ is Poisson distributed with parameter $\lambda$.

> Compute the first and second moments.

The first moment is defined as $\mu_1 = E[X]$ and the second moment $\mu_2 = E[X^2]$. However, I am not sure what $X$ is in this case. Is it simply $X=1+N_p$, and then I take the expectation of this and the square of that same expression? In this case, I presume I have two equations for two unknowns and I solve for $\alpha$ and $\lambda$? Is this the case?

Comment: X is the group size of the clients. This X is not just 1+N_p. X is a mixture between a  1+N_p and a single peak at 1.

Comment: So X is defined piecewise as $1+N_p$ with prob $(1-\alpha)$ and $1$ with prob $\alpha$?

Comment: Yes, and this results in a sum of the probability mass functions. Normally the distribution of the shifted Poisson ($N_p+1$) would be $$P(k) = \frac{\lambda^{k-1}e^{-\lambda}}{(k-1)!}$$ But now it is $$P(k) = (1-\alpha) \frac{\lambda^{k-1}e^{-\lambda}}{(k-1)!} + \alpha \mathbb{I}_{k=1}$$ where $\mathbb{I}_{c}$ is the indicator function which is 1 if the condition $c$ is true and 0 otherwise.

Comment: I see. Could I still calculate the mean and end up with something like $E[X] = \alpha + (1-\alpha)(1+ E[N_p])$? Or do I have to use that complicated thing?

Comment: BTW it is a bit strange to use $1+N_p$ for the remaining (not single bar patrons) because the Poisson variable can be 0 and then $1+N_p$ can be 1 (but it is not for single clients).

Comment: People can still go into the diner alone so I believe that is why it is defined in that manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability mass distribution for a mixture distribution of discrete distributions is like a sum of the probability mass distributions for the distributions in the mixture.

$$p(x) = \alpha p_1(x) + (1-\alpha) p_2(x) $$

**when you compute the mean you get**

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
E[X] &=& \sum_{ x} x p(x) \\
&=&  \sum_{ x } x (\alpha p_1(x) + (1-\alpha) p_2(x))\\
& =& \alpha \sum_{ x } x p_1(x) + (1-\alpha) \sum_{ x } x p_2(x)
\\ &=& \alpha E[X_1] + (1-\alpha) E[X_2]  \end{array}$$

**when you compute the variance then you get**

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
Var[X] &=& \sum_{ x} (x-E[X])^2 p(x) \\
\\ &=& \alpha \sum_{ x } (x-E[X])^2 p_1(x) + (1-\alpha) \sum_{ x } (x-E[X])^2 p_2(x)  \end{array}$$

these are not the variance of the original variables but instead the moment about a point (the point $E[X]$) which is not the original mean of the distributions.

**Moment about a point**

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\sum_{x} (x-c)^2 p(x) &=& \sum_{x}(x-\mu_x+\mu_x-c)^2 p(x)\\
 &=& \sum_{x}\left((x-\mu_x)^2 + 2 (x-\mu_x)(\mu_x-c)+ (\mu_x-c)^2 \right)p(x)\\
 &=& \sum_{x}\left((x-\mu_x)^2 + (\mu_x-c)^2 \right)p(x)\\
 &=& Var(x) + (\mu_x-c)^2\\
\end{array}$$

#### Wrap up

$$E[X] = \alpha E[X_1] + (1 -\alpha) E[X_2]$$
$$Var[X] = \alpha Var[X_1] + (1 -\alpha) Var[X_2] + \alpha (E[X_1]-E[X])^2+ (1-\alpha) (E[X_2]-E[X])^2$$